# Partially visible adjacent slides using FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a partially visible carousel.

[image: On load]

[image: When its scrolled onces]

But I want this something like:

[image: Actually what I want]

So whenever I scroll horizontally, I want the scrolling to end and the card to be centered.
How do I achieve this?

```
<FlatList
   data={cards}
   ref={(ref) => { this._flatList = ref; }}
   horizontal
   pagingEnabled
   contentContainerStyle={{ paddingLeft: itemHorizontalMargin }}
   renderItem={(data) => this._renderItem(data)}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   snapToInterval={itemWidth}
   keyExtractor = {item => item.name}
/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @subhendhu did you find any solution or a hack for this